# Como remover una session["xxxx"] c# desde javascript pero luego de 10 segundos?

Tags: javascript, c#

tengo una session["Mensaje"] en la cual almaceno el contenido de un Script (alerta toastr) para ejecutarlo en la masterPage, mi problema y pregunta es: como puedo remover esa session luego de 10 segundos. o sea que el Script se ejecute y a los 10 segundos se remueva la sesión, esto para evitar que al cargar otras pages sobre la master se vuelva a ejecutar el Script.

[image: **introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí**]

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código como texto en lugar de imagen. Será más fácil responderte y tratar de reproducir tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Existe una funcionalidad en javascript que se llama setTimeout(function, milliseconds) que te permite indicar cuanto tiempo pasara antes de que se ejecute una función

```js
console.log("iniciamos tiempo espera 10 segundos");
setTimeout(() => {console.log("ejecucion tras la espera");}, 10000)
```

Te dejo el link para que puedas revisarlo si necesitas mas documentación https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, si intente con setTimeout(function, milliseconds) pero al usarla: setTimeout(() => {function(){<%= Session["Mensaje"] = null%>);}, 10000); el valor de la session se nula sin respetar los 10 segundos.

Comment: Lo has puesto al final de tu script de la imagen?

Comment: Si, en orden primero ejecuto el script que trae la session, luego el setTimeout.